# Scala/Lift - Cannot access image uploaded until jetty is restart

Tags: image, scala, file-upload, lift

I created a file upload form, the form will take an image file from user then save it in the webapp/images/ directory.

The problem is I cannot access the image uploaded by user until jetty is restarted.

Is there anything I should add to the code? Do I need to add anything on the sitemap?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Actually I managed to get it work..i need to add ~
so it would be ~jetty-run to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try '~jetty-run' instead of 'jetty-run' when running the jetty server from sbt